# Speed up remote data retrieval using android

Tags: java, android, sql

Ok so I am doing this project for university and am struggling to think of ways of optimizing my cope to get it to run faster.

Right firstly I grab an arraylist of users by connecting to facebook, that doesnt take long at all. However for each user i need to grab data i have stored on a remote MySQL database. So to do this im using the following method...

```
// gets arraylist of users
ArrayList<User> userList= getList();
// ok so for the next bit, for each user in the arraylist i get their data on the   
database.
  for (User u: userList){
    u.setResultList(retireveData(u));
    if (u.getResultList()!=null){
        //do some magic :)
    }
  }
```

Ok so thats it... My idea was that the first time it would take ages yes but then i could store the data on a local sqlite database so it runs quicker in future and only update it when new data is added. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your database connection opened? You don't want to opening it once for every record.

Comment: AFAIK that's the way to do it. You need the data you need. A thing you could maybe do, is to do the magic in asynctask, so you dont wait for 1 to be finished before proceeding to the next.

Comment: yes i should mention i am aready using asyntask :) And yes my db is opened to access each record

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I think you need a CursorAdapter.

it updates your view as new data comes in.
see this link - http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/